# Efficient temperature control for a growbox

Tags: microcontroller, control-system, temperature, home-automation, automation

I am making a growbox controller. It has (among other things) a heater and a temperature sensor. Heater has no temperature controls, it can be turned on/off.

The objective is to maintain temperature between 23 and 27 Celsius. A simple 'if else' might do, but I am not fond of constantly switching heater. So I'm wondering, is there any algorithmic approach to do this with maximum efficiency? Don't want to reinvent another wheel, so decided to ask here first

Comment: Use a thermostat. Room 'stats cover the range of temperatures you're interested in.

Comment: Eduard, switching the heater on and off is going to provide the maximum efficiency. (Assuming you can hold a straight face when using the concept of "efficiency" in the same sentence with "heat generation," as heat generation is the diametric opposite of the idea of an efficient use of energy.) You can arrange things so that you PWM the heater, I suppose. It's still switching it on and off, just fast instead of slow. What exactly is it that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: I assume "efficiency" here means simplicity or low cost. If a thermostat isn't good enough for some reason, an off the shelf temp controller + almost any heater, for simplicity + performance (but not necessarily best price)

Comment: In terms of energy efficiency, all electric solutions short of a heat pump will deliver the same coefficient of performance of ~1. PWM does not improve this.

Answer (score 1):

Your favorite china supplier sells temperature controllers with sensor for a few bucks. They even sell them for fish aquariums, same unit. You will probable have need to add an external relay for the heaters as they only handle a few amps. I have no idea what you're heaters require. They will probably hold your temperature within a degree or so, some of them are also PID.

Answer (score 0):

Every close system with feedback has fluctuation of regulated parameter. System respond to parameter changing but the reaction has responce time, injection of system affects, etc. Reduce amplitude of that fluctuation is possible but it increase the system sofistication and cost. Algoritmes exists, some very advanced system used it. You can use some simple system, modify and adjust to you concrete application but it will not work exactly in differently place, a lot of parameters affects accuracy.